# vb.NET and complex XML structure

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to turn an xml file into a complex object class, I'm not sure why the Visual Studio/Edit/Past Special as XML Class doesn't work right. When I run this code I get the "Additional information: There is an error in XML document (24, 4) error."

```vb
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(rates))
Dim reader As New StreamReader("d:\1Q2017.xml")
Dim rts As New rates
rts = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
reader.Close()
```

My Class:

```vb
Public Class rates

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True),
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)>
Partial Public Class FILE

    Private tITLEField As String

    Private qUARTERField As String

    Private lINKField As String

    Private eXCHANGE_RATEField As String

    Private rECORDField() As FILERECORD

    Private fOOTNOTESField() As FILEFOOTNOTE

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property TITLE() As String
        Get
            Return Me.tITLEField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.tITLEField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property QUARTER() As String
        Get
            Return Me.qUARTERField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.qUARTERField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property LINK() As String
        Get
            Return Me.lINKField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.lINKField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property EXCHANGE_RATE() As String
        Get
            Return Me.eXCHANGE_RATEField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.eXCHANGE_RATEField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RECORD")>
    Public Property RECORD() As FILERECORD()
        Get
            Return Me.rECORDField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.rECORDField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("FOOTNOTE", IsNullable:=False)>
    Public Property FOOTNOTES() As FILEFOOTNOTE()
        Get
            Return Me.fOOTNOTESField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.fOOTNOTESField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class FILERECORD

    Private itemsField() As Object

    Private itemsElementNameField() As ItemsChoiceType

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("COUNTRY", GetType(String)),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FUEL_TYPE", GetType(String)),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("JURISDICTION", GetType(FILERECORDJURISDICTION)),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RATE", GetType(FILERECORDRATE)),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")>
    Public Property Items() As Object()
        Get
            Return Me.itemsField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.itemsField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName"),
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Property ItemsElementName() As ItemsChoiceType()
        Get
            Return Me.itemsElementNameField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.itemsElementNameField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class FILERECORDJURISDICTION

    Private idField As String

    Private sURCHARGEField As String

    Private valueField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property SURCHARGE() As String
        Get
            Return Me.sURCHARGEField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.sURCHARGEField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class FILERECORDRATE

    Private cOUNTRYField As String

    Private rATECHANGEField As Byte

    Private valueField As Decimal

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property COUNTRY() As String
        Get
            Return Me.cOUNTRYField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.cOUNTRYField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property RATECHANGE() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.rATECHANGEField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.rATECHANGEField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
    Public Property Value() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema:=False)>
Public Enum ItemsChoiceType

    '''<remarks/>
    COUNTRY

    '''<remarks/>
    FUEL_TYPE

    '''<remarks/>
    JURISDICTION

    '''<remarks/>
    RATE
End Enum

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)>
Partial Public Class FILEFOOTNOTE

    Private idField As String

    Private jURISDICTIONField As String

    Private valueField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return Me.idField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.idField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()>
    Public Property JURISDICTION() As String
        Get
            Return Me.jURISDICTIONField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.jURISDICTIONField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()>
    Public Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return Me.valueField
        End Get
        Set
            Me.valueField = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

End Class
```

and here is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE FILE [
<!ELEMENT FILE (TITLE, QUARTER, LINK, EXCHANGE_RATE, RECORD+, FOOTNOTES+)>
<!ELEMENT TITLE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT QUARTER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LINK (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT EXCHANGE_RATE (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT RECORD (JURISDICTION, COUNTRY, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+, FUEL_TYPE, RATE+)>
<!ELEMENT JURISDICTION (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST JURISDICTION ID CDATA #IMPLIED> 
<!ATTLIST JURISDICTION EFFECTIVE_DATE CDATA #IMPLIED> 
<!ATTLIST JURISDICTION SURCHARGE CDATA #IMPLIED> 
<!ELEMENT COUNTRY (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FUEL_TYPE (#PCDATA)>  
<!ELEMENT RATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST RATE COUNTRY (US|CAN) #REQUIRED>  
<!ATTLIST RATE RATECHANGE (1|0) #REQUIRED>  

<!ELEMENT FOOTNOTES (FOOTNOTE+)>
<!ELEMENT FOOTNOTE (#PCDATA)> 
<!ATTLIST FOOTNOTE ID CDATA #IMPLIED>  
<!ATTLIST FOOTNOTE JURISDICTION CDATA #IMPLIED>  
]>
<FILE>
  <TITLE> Final Fuel Tax Rates </TITLE>
  <QUARTER>1Q2017</QUARTER>
  <LINK>http://www.iftach.org/TaxMatrix/charts/1Q2017.xml</LINK>
  <EXCHANGE_RATE>U.S./Canada Exchange Rate 1.3395 - 0.7465</EXCHANGE_RATE>
  <RECORD>
    <JURISDICTION ID="#15"  >AB</JURISDICTION>
    <COUNTRY>CAN</COUNTRY>
    <FUEL_TYPE>Gasoline</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.4942</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1749</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Special Diesel</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.5185</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1835</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Gasohol</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3674</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Propane</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.3527</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1248</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>LNG</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.1068</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.0378</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>CNG</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">1.0681</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.3780</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Ethanol</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3674</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Methanol</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.4290</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1518</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>E-85</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.3863</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1367</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>M-85</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.4388</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1553</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>A55</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.4244</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="1">0.1502</RATE>
      <FUEL_TYPE>Biodiesel</FUEL_TYPE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="0">0.3674</RATE>
      <RATE COUNTRY="CAN" RATECHANGE="0">0.1300</RATE>
  </RECORD>
</FILE>
```

I apologize if this has already been covered, but I search high and low and could not find an example of how to handle these, the XML formats correctly when trying the online formatters.

Comment: Is this xml format fixed? It's kind of silly to define an item's properties on the same level as the item, i.e. `<FUEL_TYPE>Methanol</FUEL_TYPE>` and on the same level `<RATE COUNTRY="US" RATECHANGE="1">0.4290</RATE>`. While xml preserves order when serializing, it could be lost by doing a number of operation on the .Net classes.

Comment: I agree completely, unfortunately, I have no control over the layout of this XML file as it is coming from a different company. the only thing there will be more of are the RECORD elements, there will be one for each US state and some provinces.

Comment: Well if you were to serialize this as is, you would end up with an `IEnumerable(Of FUEL_TYPE)` and an `IEnumerable(Of RATE)`. Then the FUEL_TYPE at index y corresponds to RATE at index `x = (y * 2)` and `x = (y * 2 + 1)`. Is that what you'd want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classes seem fine. Instead of nesting them in a new class, `rates`, just deserialize to the `FILE` class.

```vb
Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(FILE))
Dim f As FILE
Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("XMLFile1.xml")
    f = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
End Using
```

**EDIT**

In my testing environment

- Tested with .NET frameworks 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, and 4.6.2. It works
- Added fully qualified class names (namespaces before some .NET class names so you don't need to import them).
- To test, I added a new xml file to my project, then copied the entire XML to the file, and right clicked on the file >> properties >> set `Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy Always`. I did this because I don't have `"d:\1Q2017.xml"`
- I also made sure that the `FILE` class is marked `Public`. If it's defined in `Module1`, then declare `Public Module Module1`, or move outside of `Module1` and just make it `Public`

[image]

Comment: Which version of dotNET Framework are you using with this example? I'm getting a slightly different outcome.

Comment: @user7043256 all that I have on my machine. See the points in my edit. I don't see how this wouldn't work. Maybe there's something else going on. Can you confirm that you can do this in a new console app?

Answer (score 1):

The XML you are receiving is not valid.

The FILE element is declared as follows:

```
<!ELEMENT FILE (TITLE, QUARTER, LINK, EXCHANGE_RATE, RECORD+, FOOTNOTES+)>
```

But the FILE tag in the actual XML doesn't have a FOOTNOTES child element.

Comment: For clarity, `+` indicates that the element must appear at least once.

Comment: Does that translate to the .net classes at all?

Comment: ok so if I can take off everything so I only have the root as <FILE> </FILE> would that make a difference?

Comment: You don't need the DTD once you have created the classes from the schema. If you want to validate against it, look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing(v=vs.110).aspx.